# Проблема обновления PHP из репозитория Webtatic

Tags: php, linux, centos, update

Имеется сервер на CentOS 6, где хостится сайт муниципального учреждения. На этом сервере нужно обновить PHP (с версии 5.6) и MySQL (с версии 5.1) до актуальных версий. Пакеты php установлены из репозитория Webtatic. Через yum update можно обновить лишь до максимально актуальной версии 5.6, более новых версий для обновления в репозитории нет. Если устанавливать пакеты из других репозиториев, то они начинают конфликтовать и ломается весь php (соответственно, падает и сайт). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно максимально безопасно обновить пакеты не ломая при этом сайт?

Comment: переписать сайт под 7. версию)

Comment: Надо установить 7 версию php с помощью yum install, переключиться на неё, а старую удалить потом через yum remove. Update не поможет

Comment: А как "переключиться на неё"? Я пытаюсь нагуглить, где в конфиге Апача меняется что-то, но не выходит. Может кто нибудь приблизительную ориентировку дать?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае необходимо взять и развернуть тестовый стенд с актуальными версиями окружения. Перенести туда сайт и устранить все возникающие ошибки. После этого у вас два варианта:

1. Сделать текущее окружение основным.
2. Временно переключить работу на тестовое окружение, обновить основное и перенести туда все работы.

Comment: Это вполне очевидно (собственно, я этим в итоге и занимаюсь). Было необходимо быстрое  решение для оперативного обновления и дальнейшего функционирования сервера. Тогда может подскажите, могут ли быть подобные проблемы из-за того, что php-код сайта был написан под пятую версию? Несовместимость/конфликт из-за версии PHP?